# Delegate (virtual) IP is set to both nodes, even if primary and secondary is well identified

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pgpool

I am very new to pgpool, and I want to find why in my 2 nodes cluster, the delegate ip is set on both the nodes, even if the cluster is up, and everything seems fine.

From node-0 (198) :

```
/usr/bin/pcp_node_info -n 0 -h 192.165.10.198 -p 9898 -U pgadmin -w --verbose
Hostname               : 192.165.10.198
Port                   : 5432
Status                 : 2
Weight                 : 0.500000
Status Name            : up
Role                   : primary
Replication Delay      : 0
Replication State      : 
Replication Sync State : 
Last Status Change     : 2023-06-08 16:48:29

/usr/bin/pcp_node_info -n 1 -h 192.165.10.198 -p 9898 -U pgadmin -w --verbose
Hostname               : 192.165.10.199
Port                   : 5432
Status                 : 2
Weight                 : 0.500000
Status Name            : up
Role                   : standby
Replication Delay      : 0
Replication State      : streaming
Replication Sync State : async
Last Status Change     : 2023-06-08 16:48:29

ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:0e:24:b4:61:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.165.10.198/24 brd 192.165.10.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.165.10.200/24 scope global secondary eth0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::140e:24ff:feb4:6148/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

From node-1 (199) :

```
/usr/bin/pcp_node_info -n 0 -h 192.165.10.199 -p 9898 -U pgadmin -w --verbose
Hostname               : 192.165.10.198
Port                   : 5432
Status                 : 2
Weight                 : 0.500000
Status Name            : up
Role                   : primary
Replication Delay      : 0
Replication State      : 
Replication Sync State : 
Last Status Change     : 2023-06-08 16:47:14

/usr/bin/pcp_node_info -n 1 -h 192.165.10.199 -p 9898 -U pgadmin -w --verbose
Hostname               : 192.165.10.199
Port                   : 5432
Status                 : 2
Weight                 : 0.500000
Status Name            : up
Role                   : standby
Replication Delay      : 0
Replication State      : streaming
Replication Sync State : async
Last Status Change     : 2023-06-08 16:47:14

ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:44:fe:04:53:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.165.10.199/24 brd 192.165.10.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.165.10.200/24 scope global secondary eth0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4c36:37f0:f14d:36ca/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As it seems that the primary node is the node-0 (198), I tried to removed the delegate ip (200) : `/sbin/ip addr del 192.165.10.200/24 dev eth0`

But a few seconds later, on the same node, in journactl I receive that :

```
juin 12 13:47:20 node-1 pgpool[1021]: [75-1] 2023-06-12 13:47:20: pid 1021: LOG:  successfully acquired the delegate IP:"192.165.10.200"
juin 12 13:47:20 node-1 pgpool[1021]: [75-2] 2023-06-12 13:47:20: pid 1021: DETAIL:  'if_up_cmd' returned with success
```

I don't understand why this is happening.